# Testing the collection of Bernoulli variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bernoulli-distribution

Suppose that I am throwing a triple dice (i.e, three dices simultaneously) $n$ times. Then number of times that the sum of these three dices $k=3,\ldots,18$ appears is my sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is the random variable $S_k$. Now I have derived that $S_k$ follows binomial distribution $B(n,p_k)$ where $p_k$ are the probabilities derived from $p_k := P(\sum_{i=1}^{3}X^{(i)} = k)$.

Given a sample $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, how do I test that $S_k$ follows the theoretical distribution? Note that for each $k=3,\ldots,18$, I have one value $S_k$ for the whole sample.

Comment: $S_k$ does not follow a Bernoulli distribution or a binomial distribution.  But you can calculate the distribution and then compare the observations against this.  A $\chi^2$ test might be one possibility

Comment: If $X_i$ follow uniform distribution, then $X_i^{(1)} + X_i^{(2)} + X_i^{(3)}$ follow a calculated distribution (characterised by some vector $\mathbf{p} = [p_3,\ldots,p_{18}]$). Therefore the rv $S_k = \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1_{Y = k}$ follows binomial distribution, right?

Comment: The probabilities for $S_k$ with $k=3,\ldots,18$ are $\frac{1}{216}$, $\frac{3}{216}$, $\frac{6}{216}$, $\frac{10}{216}$, $\frac{15}{216}$, $\frac{21}{216}$, $\frac{25}{216}$, $\frac{27}{216}$, $\frac{27}{216}$, $\frac{25}{216}$, $\frac{21}{216}$, $\frac{15}{216}$, $\frac{10}{216}$, $\frac{6}{216}$, $\frac{3}{216}$, $\frac{1}{216}$.  This is not a binomial distribution

Comment: @Henry thanks for your reply. The probabilities that you have mentioned are the probabilities for the sums of three dices, i.e, $P(\sum_{i=1}^{3}X^{(i)} = k)$ for $k$ between 3 and 18. Now $S_k$ is the number $m<n$ of the cases when the sum of the dices was equal to $k$. For instance, if we had $X_1 = (1,2,1), X_2 = (3,1,1)$ and $X_3 = (1,1,2)$ then $S_4 = 2$ (for $X_1$ and $X_3$).

Comment: OK - so the expected values of $S_k$ are those probabilities multiplied by $n$.  And you can compare the observations against this. A $χ^2$ test might be one possibility

Comment: Does it mean that I have to perform $k$ tests in total?

Comment: No - a suitable $\chi^2$-test or similar would be a single test of whether the whole of the observed data was close to the predicted probabilities of the hypothesis

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find any material which would explain how to perform a chi-squared test for 13 nonidentically distributed variables $S_3 \sim B(n, p_3) ,\ldots,S_{18} \sim B(n,p_{18})$ at once. Could you provide me with some book name or a link perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a worked example in R:

First simulate the dice, say 10,000 times:

```
set.seed(2022)
numsides <- 6
numdice <- 3 
cases <- 10000
simsumdice <- function(sides,dice){
  sum(sample(sides, dice, replace=TRUE))
  }
sims <- replicate(cases, simsumdice(sides=numsides, dice=numdice))
results <- table(factor(sims, levels = numdice:(numsides*numdice))
results
```

to get

```
   3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18 
  43  136  287  458  668  957 1191 1269 1205 1163 1005  708  467  255  132   56
```

You might have expected about $\frac{10000}{216} \approx 46.3$ values of $3$ and similarly of $18$, but this is a simulation.

Then compare these simulation results to the theoretical probabilities, i.e. to the expected numbers of each sum, for example using a [chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test)

```
theoryprob <- c(1,3,6,10,15,21,25,27,27,25,21,15,10,6,3,1)/216
chisq.test(results, p=theoryprob)
```

and see

```
        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  results
X-squared = 10.459, df = 15, p-value = 0.7899
```

and this $p$-value fails to reject the hypothesis that the simulation comes from this theoretical distribution.